# Physics vector constructor, magnitude and unit vector functions not working c++

Tags: c++, class, this, copy-constructor, this-pointer

I am writing a class called Vector which represents a 3-dimensional vector. I need a constructor which can take a pre-existing Vector object and create a new one from it. This is the constructor:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector &v1){
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        components[i] = v1.components[i];
}
```

This is the note the compiler gives me:

```
candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Vector *' 
to 'const Vector &' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
Vector::Vector(const Vector &v1){
```

I also have a magnitude function:

```
double Vector::magnitude(){
    return std::pow(dot(this, this), 0.5);
}
```

I come from java so by the use of this I mean to say use this instance of the class and pass it in as a Vector to the dot function. I get the following error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'Vector *' to 'Vector'
return std::pow(dot(this, this), 0.5);
```

I also have a unit vector function where I try to use my constructor above to create a copy of the Vector object using `this`.

```
Vector Vector::getUnitVector(){
    Vector unit(this);
    unit.scale(1/unit.magnitude());
    return unit;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector'
Vector unit(this);
```

How can I fix these errors? Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `this` to `*this`, `this` is a pointer if you want a reference `Vector&` you have to first dereference the this pointer with `&`

Comment: Despite some similarities in the syntax, C++ and Java are *very* different languages. Learning C++ by guessing from Java knowledge will not work. You should learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: Yeh true. I just thought I could get some specific help for this.

Comment: where is definition of `dot`? Note compiler is complaining about how `dot` is used. Most probably you want `dot(*this, *this)`.

Comment: I have fixed the errors but now I get this Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Vector::toString()", referenced from:
      _main in main-3acaf8.o
  "Vector::Vector()", referenced from:
      _main in main-3acaf8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Unless you have explicitly defined (i.e. implemented) `Vector::toString()` any usage of it cannot be resolved by the linker.  The error messages suggests exactly that - the function is used, but not defined.

Comment: In my header file I define it using void toString(); @Peter

Comment: @Tom Finet "In my header file I define it using void toString();" - Ok, but do you also *implement* it somewhere?

Comment: Yes I implement it like so: void Vector::toString(){
 printf("x: %lf, y: %lf, z: %lf\n", 
  components[0], components[1], components[2]);
}

Comment: @TomFinet "_In my header file I define it using void toString();_" That's not a definition. That's a declaration. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `void toString();` is a declaration, but is not a definition.    Odds are you declared it in the header file, defined it in another source file, but either didn't compile that other source file or (if you did compile it) didn't include the object in the link.  A key property of C++ is a model of separate compilation - unless you EXPLICITLY include source files and objects in your build, they will not magically be compiled or calls of functions resolved.

Comment: I've voted to close  because (1)  you are providing partial information - you need to provide a [mcve].   (2)   You are obviously doing things in a "Java way" and assuming - incorrectly - things work the same in C++.    This means, each time someone tries to help, another problem will emerge.  That wastes people's time (their effort much greater than yours) and you need to read up on how to do things in C++ - including how to build programs - rather than assuming C++ does things like Java does.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing pointers with references.  If you have a pointer `p` (`Vector*` or `this` and need a reference (`Vector&`), you need to say `*p` to dereference it.

If you have a reference `r` and need a pointer, you can say `&r` to get the address of the object, which is a pointer.

For example, instead of your code:

```
Vector unit(this);
```

You need to say:

```
Vector unit(*this);
```

Because the copy constructor takes `const Vector&` (reference), not `const Vector*` (pointer).